# Webpack can't handle my SCSS files even though I have the correct loaders

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Seem to be having a problem with Webpack not being able to compile my SCSS files. I have a file a `package.json` file and `webpack.config.js` file generated from using `webpack-cli init` package.

Below is the webpack error I am getting when trying to compile when importing my `.scss` file into my `.js`:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/styles.scss 2:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| $green: green;
> body {
|     background-color: $green;
| }
 @ ./src/js/index.js 2:0-29
```

Below is my `webpack.config.js` file that was generated using the `webpack-cli init` command. I had to add the scss loader stuff to the `module.rule` but I'm sure it's done correctly.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/js/index.js',

    output: {
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'html')
    },

    plugins: [new webpack.ProgressPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js')],
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],

                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            {
                                modules: false
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    devServer: {
        open: true
    }
};
```

Below is the `package.json` file that was generate from the `webpack-cli init` command

```
{
  "name": "test-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^0.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "description": "My webpack project",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  }
}
```

I'm sure I have everything that I need installed to make this work but no matter what I try it doesn't want to compile my `.scss` files :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to remove one of the curly braces on the test for scss. Although you described how the scss filess should be handled. The description is not directly under the rules array like you handled the .jsx/.js files.
I hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I can't believe I missed that